# React - Close a custom context menu when open another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contextmenu

I'm creating a custom context menu. Code below:

```js
function useContextMenu() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = () => setIsShow(false);
    const hideEvent = "click blur";
    hideEvent.split(" ").forEach((e) => {
      window.addEventListener(e, handleClick);
    });

    return () => {
      hideEvnet.split(" ").forEach((e) => {
        window.removeEventListener(e, handleClick);
      });
    };
  }, []);


  function contextMenu() {
    return (isShow && createPortal( < ContextMenu position = {
          position
        }
        />,document.body))
      }

      function onClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setPosition({
          x: event.pageX,
          y: event.pageY
        });
        setIsShow(true);
      }

      return [contextMenu, onClick];
    }


    function AlbumCard({
      index,
      album
    }) {
      const [contextMenu, onClick] = useContextMenu();

      return ( <
        div className = "album-card"
        onContextMenu = {
          (e) => onClick(e)
        } > {
          contextMenu()
        } <
        /div>
      );
    }
```

If I click outside of context menu it works great.
But, if I right-click to open another one, the old one doesn't close.
I think the problem is each `<AlbumCard/>` has it own context menu portal, I've tried to add "menucontext" to the event listener but it doesn't work.